# Ciclar un arreglo de un objeto de MongoDB en Python con Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, mongodb

Estoy tratando de ciclar un arreglo que viene de un nodo en mongoDB, este es el objeto de Mongo:

```
{
  "nombre": "Sebastián Yatra",
  "paises":["México","Argentina","Perú"]
}
```

El controlador de la vista es este

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from pymongo import MongoClient

def paises( req ):
  client = MongoClient()
  obj = { 'obj': client['mydb']['paises'].find() }
  return render( req, 'index.html', obj )
```

Así lo estoy ciclando en la vista con Django

```
<h5>{{ obj.nombre }}</h5> #aquí si imprime Sebastián Yatra
<ul>
{% for pais in obj.paises %}
  <li>{{ pais[0] }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
<p>{{ len(obj.paises) }} encontados</p>
```

Primero me dice

> Could not parse this remainder: 'obj.paises' from 'len (obj.paises)'

Y si quito la línea me dice

> Could not parse this remainder '[0]' from 'pais[0]'

Soy aún novato con Python, mi experiencia me dice que en primera debo declarar una variable que vaya incrementando tipo `pais[i]` pero no se donde declarar la i = 0, y luego donde incrementarla.

Que puedo hacer con estos 2 erorres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero, con `% for pais in obj.paises %` ya estás iterando sobre la lista de forma que `pais` es el item de turno ("México","Argentina","Perú", etc). No necesitas "indexar" sobre `pais`, basta con:

```
<li>{{ pais }}</li>
```

Por otro lado, para mostrar la longitud de la lista puedes usar el built-in [`length`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#length):

```
<p>{{ obj.paises|length }} encontrados</p>
```

Por lo tanto tu templete debería quedar algo así:

```
<h5>{{ obj.nombre }}</h5>    
<ul>
  {% for pais in obj.paises %}
    <li>{{pais}}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>    
<p>{{ obj.paises|length }} encontrados</p>
```

Lo cual para tu ejemplo nos mostraría:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h5>Sebastián Yatra</h5>
        <ul>
            <li>México</li>
            <li>Argentina</li>
            <li>Perú</li>
        </ul>
        <p>3 encontrados</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias sensei.